# real(8) resolution, data overflow

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I have the following code which does not compile using gfortran:

```
program test_overflow
    real(8) a,b
    b=0.d0
    a=1e39
    write(*,*) a*b
end program
```

The error output from gfortran is

```
test.f90:4.14:

        a=1e39
              1
Error: Real constant overflows its kind at (1)
```

I wonder what is the issue here. As far as I remember, `real(8)` should give a double precision range of 10 to the power of -100 to +100 (approximately), am I wrong about this?

Comment: I just realized that I should be using 1d39 for double precision constants. This issue is solved.

Answer (score 3):

Use `a=1d39` instead of `a=1e39`.

`e` denotes single precision.

`d` denotes double precision.

You may want to refer to the documentation for [Double Precision Constants](http://h21007.www2.hp.com/portal/download/files/unprot/fortran/docs/lrm/lrm0027.htm).

Comment: @Rain actually answered this himself in a comment almost a year ago, but it should be in an answer, and you've clarified and included a nice link to supporting documentation. Nice job on that. Hopefully Rain comes back to accept this.

Answer (score 1):

The literal

```
1e139
```

is a default real. It doesn't matter what is on the left-hand side of the assignment, Fortran always evaluates expressions without the surrounding context. The value `10^139` is too large for the default real in your processor.

`real(8)` may or may not give you the double precision. Often it does, but it is compiler specific. If you insist on the kind 8, although I won't recommend it, you get floating point literals of the same kind by using the suffix

```
1e139_8
```

It is better to place the value 8 to a named constant

```
integer, parameter :: wp = 8
```

(though it is better to use other methods, than the magic number 8)
and then you can do

```
real(wp) :: x
```

and

```
1e139_wp
```

There is an odl method, which distinguishes just default (sometimes called single precision) and double precision reals. In that case you declare your variables as

```
double precision :: x
```

and literals as

```
1d139
```

Mixing the two methods (`real(8)` and `1d139`) is strange.